# c# if bool not working

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

Edit: so I'm guessing by the down votes, people are having issues reproducing the problem? It's not hard for me, copy the code I included, read the original expected and actual results, run program, make a few clicks and drags. I can reproduce this every single time. It doesn't really matter because I solved the issue but have to wait to considered it answered. So if the admins who put this hold could just delete the post or mark my answer as the answer that'd be great. I provided everything as outlined by the guideline, with the possible opinion of "minimal code". It had the desired and actual result, the steps to reproduce and I have no idea how to make it any more clear without doing a screen recording. If you beg the differ, how about you actually ask for clarification on something so I can see the mistake.

Original:

I have an interesting issue here. I'm trying to make a simple rubber band selection in C# and I have everything working except for a weird bug if I don't make a selection.

Expected result: MouseDown/MouseUp without moving mouse and no selection should be made after moving the mouse.

Actual result: MouseDown/MouseUp without moving mouse, then when I mouse the mouse, the selection is drawn as I move my mouse. If I click, the selection disappears. Then if I click again and mouse the mouse, the new selection is continuously redrawn.

I added a label to my form to check the state of the bool. When I do this, everything works as expected. However, once I comment out the `label1.Text` line, it's no longer working as expected. I've tried adding multiple bools to resolve said issue but no avail.

So why is the bool not being recognized unless I set the label text? P.S. I'm a newbie to C# so I welcome any criticism. I pulled this code from http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/use-a-rubber-band-box-to-let-the-user-select-an-area-in-a-picture-in-c/

Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RubberBand
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Bitmap m_Orig = null;
        private int X0, X1, Y0, Y1;
        private bool sArea, isDown, hasMoved = false;
        private Bitmap sImg = null;
        private Graphics sGraph = null;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_Orig = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 27)
            {
                if (!sArea) return;
                sArea = false;
                isDown = false;
                hasMoved = false;

                sImg = null;
                sGraph = null;
                pictureBox1.Image = m_Orig;
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            sArea = true;
            isDown = true;
            //label1.Text = isDown.ToString();
            X0 = e.X;
            Y0 = e.Y;

            sImg = new Bitmap(m_Orig);
            sGraph = Graphics.FromImage(sImg);
            pictureBox1.Image = sImg;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!sArea) return;
            hasMoved = true;
            //label1.Text = isDown.ToString();

            if (isDown)
            {
                X1 = e.X;
                Y1 = e.Y;

                sGraph.DrawImage(m_Orig, 0, 0);

                using (Pen select_pen = new Pen(Color.Red))
                {
                    select_pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
                    Rectangle rect = MakeRectangle(X0, Y0, X1, Y1);
                    sGraph.DrawRectangle(select_pen, rect);
                }

                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!sArea) return;
            if (!hasMoved) return;

            sArea = false;
            hasMoved = false;
            isDown = false;
            //label1.Text = isDown.ToString();
            sImg = null;
            sGraph = null;
            pictureBox1.Image = m_Orig;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

            Rectangle rect = MakeRectangle(X0, Y0, X1, Y1);
            if ((rect.Width > 0) && (rect.Height > 0))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(rect.ToString());
            }
        }

        private Rectangle MakeRectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
        {
            return new Rectangle(
                Math.Min(x0, x1),
                Math.Min(y0, y1),
                Math.Abs(x0 - x1),
                Math.Abs(y0 - y1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My first guess after you said that it works fine when setting a seemingly unrelated label would be that setting the label is causing the form to be re-drawn or something. What happens if you just set the label text to a string?

Comment: I'm really confused at what is wrong, running the code on my machine seems to function the same as the original tutorial, whether or not the label code is there.

Comment: @Cyral I'll test this shortly and let you know. I'm running Windows 8.1 and using VS 2015 Community edition.

When do you want me to label to a string?

Comment: Just set the label to "test" or something and see if it still works, then comment it out again.

Comment: @Cyral, I do NOT get the expected result...

Comment: if you follow the code from the link, you get the expected results. I believe this is because it's calling the MessageBox. I'm trying to implement code to prevent it from displaying the messagebox if there isn't a selection...

Thus, I implemented the hasMoved bool. That gave me the result I was looking for, but it came with the issue that it's drawing the selection when I don't think it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after more research, this appears to be a known issue. I have resolved my issue thanks to this page: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8e85eb78-77f2-485f-9bd3-3eaa44233a8a/mousedown-and-mousemove-events

Here is the updated and working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RubberBand
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Bitmap m_Orig = null;
        private int X0, X1, Y0, Y1;
        private bool sArea, hasMoved = false;
        private Bitmap sImg = null;
        private Graphics sGraph = null;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_Orig = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 27)
            {
                if (!sArea) return;
                sArea = false;
                hasMoved = false;

                sImg = null;
                sGraph = null;
                pictureBox1.Image = m_Orig;
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            sArea = true;

            X0 = e.X;
            Y0 = e.Y;

            sImg = new Bitmap(m_Orig);
            sGraph = Graphics.FromImage(sImg);
            pictureBox1.Image = sImg;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (!sArea) return;
                hasMoved = true;

                X1 = e.X;
                Y1 = e.Y;

                sGraph.DrawImage(m_Orig, 0, 0);

                using (Pen select_pen = new Pen(Color.Red))
                {
                    select_pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
                    Rectangle rect = MakeRectangle(X0, Y0, X1, Y1);
                    sGraph.DrawRectangle(select_pen, rect);
                }

                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!sArea) return;
            if (!hasMoved) return;

            sArea = false;
            hasMoved = false;

            sImg = null;
            sGraph = null;
            pictureBox1.Image = m_Orig;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

            Rectangle rect = MakeRectangle(X0, Y0, X1, Y1);
            if ((rect.Width > 0) && (rect.Height > 0))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(rect.ToString());
            }
        }

        private Rectangle MakeRectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
        {
            return new Rectangle(
                Math.Min(x0, x1),
                Math.Min(y0, y1),
                Math.Abs(x0 - x1),
                Math.Abs(y0 - y1));
        }
    }
}
```